# Duplicate DOM Element and Sync changes

Tags: javascript

I want to `duplicate` a DOM element and place them everywhere on the DOM tree, so that changes on each would be sync.

`clone` it would loose its sync, and it is known that one DOM element could not be appended in 2 different DOM as well..

So I wondered what is the modern way to achieve this behavior?
I read about `MutationObserver` but working with this is still not as elegant as it could be.

Comment: MutationObserver seems a bit clunky at first but is likely the best tool for the job. What sort of things do you need to sync?

Comment: I'd like to create `n` copies of a single element and whenever this element changes so the copies

Comment: Depending on what kind of element you're talking about, either updating all the copies in a `change` event handler or using a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) are the ways to go.

Comment: That's not very specific about what those changes would be or what kind of elements you are talking about. Just repeating what you already stated

Comment: I do not see why it matters ..
But this is a `div` that frequency change his dataset,
and I would like that changes to apply on every copy, without having to loop on each if possible

Comment: If it's just a dataset issue if all elements have same object reference no need for an observer

Comment: This is exactlty what I want!
how do I do it? @charlietfl